# How to prevent access to all but ONE file with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to prevent access to all files but ONE using .htaccess, in this way but it does not work.

```
<Files accessibleFile.php>
allow from all
</Files>

<Filesmatch "^((?!accessibleFile\.php).)*$">
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic
</Filesmatch>

<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Any one can help?
**Added**: I still want to have logged access to the other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the file in a seperate folder and secure this folder using .htaccess and .htpasswd

Comment: It is always recommend to use absolute path for htpasswd file to avoid quirk behavior.

Comment: OK, is there an option to stay in the same directory ? @timdream agreed, I used non absolute path for the example.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "is there an option to stay in the same directory"

Comment: I was trying to keep my script in the same dir as the others. But your solution has some other advantages. So I keep it +1.

Comment: You do not always have the luxury of moving that file to a distinct folder. Real-world example: If you want to block/allow certain files in a Wordpress-Installation/wp-admin...

Answer (score 3):

This is enough:

```
Deny from all

<Files "allowed.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Also note that your `<Limit GET POST>` directive makes your site vulnerable to [HTTP Verb Tampering](http://www.imperva.com/resources/glossary/http_verb_tampering.html).

Comment: I see that my question is not clear, I want to have a logged access to all but ONE, so this option does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go**
(Apache 2.2, minor modification on the Allow+Satisfy needed for Apache 2.4+):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "please log in"    
AuthUserFile /is/htdocs/foo/.htpasswd
require user Mike

<FilesMatch "(admin-ajax.php|info.jpg)">
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```